# How to replace an any kind of element with a div of equal boxing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm around trying to remove a DOM element (I'll put it elsewhere) and I need the position of the sibling elements do not change.

I tried some variations of this.

```
var elem = $("#theElement");
var ghost = $('<div></div>');
ghost.css({
   width: elem.outerWidth(true),
   height: elem.outerHeight(true),
   margin: 0
});
         
elem.replaceWith(ghost);
```

But the document collapses slightly.

I know I can just change the visibility of the element, but not what I need. I'll put it somewhere else in the DOM and can not be duplicated.

### The Question

How to replace any kind of element with a div that occupies the same space?

**EDIT**

Keep in mind that i can not change the source element attributes.

I do not know in advance which item and which properties it has, just take it out of where it is and move it elsewhere.

The jQuery documentation says:

**.outerHeight(true):** if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included.

**.outerWidth(true):** If includeMargin is omitted or false, the padding and border are included in the calculation; if true, the margin is also included.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rMYd4o?p=preview)

Comment: outerWidth(true) and outerHeight(true), [here](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/#outerWidth-includeMargin) says: "if true, the margin is also included."

Comment: Sorry, but something mentioned in 'Additional Notes' also.

Comment: "dimensions may be incorrect when the page is zoomed by the user" is not the case.

Comment: Your plunker does not appear to be working for me... I'm just getting the default page.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the margin given by the browser, called user agent stylesheet in dev tools.

I have modified your plunk to have css like this

```
h1 {
  color: red;
  margin:0px !important;  
}
```

Issue seemed to be resolved.

EDIT:

I have edited your code to be something like this:

```
$(function(){
  var elem = $("h1");
  var ghost = $('<div></div>');
       ghost.css({
         width: elem.outerWidth(),
         height: elem.outerHeight(),
         margin: 21
       });
```

Since you can not modify the source, identify what styling the browser is putting onto it and give your ghost element the same styling.

To detect what css the browser is putting onto your element, refer

```
http://www.iecss.com
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/html.css
http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css
```

Comment: Keep in mind that i can not change the source element attributes.

Comment: is it because you need to copy that 'h1' element somewhere else? Any reason why you can't copy it before modifying this 'h1' to hide it?

Comment: Yes. I do not know in advance which item and which properties it has, just take it out of where it is and move it elsewhere.

Comment: sorry, what about a div without margin? i need a general solution.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, get it from the DOM, whatever the final valve on the div is (0 or non 0) can be obtained, put it in a variable and pass it your ghosts css

Comment: That's exactly what I try to do. but how?

Comment: Updated the answer. There is no direct way you can get those values, I suggest you go through the documentation and check what your values are going to be based on your hierarchy of the DOM